# What is on the stack before my program starts?

Tags: assembly, stack

I am learning High Level Assembly Language at the moment, and am playing with the stack to better understand everything.

I note that in the following program, I can pop the contents of the stack, without ever having pushed anything onto it 37 times before the program crashes.

```
ike1: uns32 := 1;

begin test1;

while (ike1 < 38) do
pop(eax);
stdout.put(ike1, nl);
stdout.put("ESP: ", esp, nl);
stdout.put("EAX:", eax, nl, nl);
add(1, ike1);
endwhile;
end test1;
```

Each time the stack is popped into EAX, and the output of EAX shows random data each time.

I firstly don't understand how this is possible, as I thought every program was seggregated into its own private memory space?

In any event I am popping data of the stack...what would this be, and would it be affecting any other running programs?

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the execution of `main()` a bunch of other operations need to be done by the OS to properly setup the environment before control of the execution is handled to your application. So, most of what's on the stack at this point is garbage left from previous operations.

Right before `main()` is executed, you can expect to find `argc` and `argv` on the stack as well.

**EDIT:**

A comment from a user kinda challenged me to go through the process of debugging an assembly application in **gdb** and examining the stack to backup a statement I made on the original answer.

So please consider the following assembly code written in *nasm*:

```
section .data

  mymsg db "hello, world", 0xa  ; string with a carriage-return
  mylen equ $-mymsg             ; string length in bytes

section .text
global mystart                ; make the main function externally visible

mystart:
    ; prepare the arguments for syscall write()
    push dword mylen          ; msg length                           
    push dword mymsg          ; msg to write
    push dword 1              ; file descriptor number

    ; call write()
    mov eax, 0x4              ; 0x4 identifies syscall write()
    sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) syscalls needs "extra space" on stack
    int 0x80                  ; trigger the call

    ; clean up the stack
    add esp, 16               ; 3 args * 4 bytes/arg + 4 bytes extra space = 16 bytes

    ; prepare argument for syscall exit()
    push dword 0              ; exit status returned to the operating system

    ; call exit()
    mov eax, 0x1              ; 0x1 identifies syscall exit()
    sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
    int 0x80                  ; trigger the call
```

I compiled this on Mac OS X with:

```
nasm -f macho -o hello.o hello.nasm
ld -o hello -e mystart hello.o
```

As you can probably tell by the source code, the start of the application is defined by `mystart`, and it doesn't take any parameters.

Now, let's make this investigation a little more exciting by opening this program in **gdb**:

```
gdb ./hello
```

After **gdb** has loaded, it's important for educational purposes to set a cmd line parameter for this application even though it wasn't written to accept any.

```
set args deadbeef
```

The application is still not running at this point. We need to set a *breakpoint* to the beginning of the *main* function so can inspect the stack to see what's going on before our application starts executing it's own code:

```
break mystart
```

Execute the command `run` on gdb to start the application and break the execution. Now we can inspect the stack with:

```
x/20xw $esp
```

outputs:

```
(gdb) x/20xw $esp
0xbffff8cc: 0x00002000  0x00000000  0x00000002  0xbffff96c
0xbffff8dc: 0xbffff98b  0x00000000  0xbffff994  0xbffff9b0
0xbffff8ec: 0xbffff9c1  0xbffff9d1  0xbffffa0b  0xbffffa40
0xbffff8fc: 0xbffffa5b  0xbffffa86  0xbffffa97  0xbffffaad
0xbffff90c: 0xbffffad8  0xbffffafa  0xbffffb06  0xbffffb28
```

Yes Sir, this command prints the contents of the stack. It tells **gdb** to show 20 words in hexadecimal format starting at the address stored by the `$esp` register.

Let's see, `$esp` actually points to `0xbffff8cc`, ok but examining what's stored by this memory address reveals *another* address: `0x00002000`. To what does it points to???

```
(gdb) x/20sw 0x00002000
0x2000 <mymsg>:  "hello, world\n"
```

Not a shocker, right?! So let's take a look at what some of the other addresses of the table are pointing to:

```
(gdb) x/1sw 0xbffff96c
0xbffff96c:  "/Developer/workspace/asm/hello"
```

Wow. That's actually the original application's **name and path** stored right there on the stack! Awesome, let's continue to the next interesting address of the table:

```
(gdb) x/1sw 0xbffff98b
0xbffff98b:  "deadbeef"
```

Jackpot! The cmd line argument we passed upon executing our application also got stored in the stack. So as I've stated before, among the garbage stored in the stack before your application executes, you can also find cmd line parameters that were used to execute the application even when the `main()` function of the application is `void` and doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough HLA, but for 'normal' win32 assembly programs there aren't any parameters to the entry point function (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/25/10168020.aspx)).

Comment: win32 console applications that were defined to NOT receive any input parameters on the `main()` function **WILL** have these parameters **stored in the stack anyway**. I updated my answer to show a step-by-step example on how to verify this information on Mac OS X, but it can be used for Linux as well if you change the compiling settings. I'm quite sure that in Ollydbg this is a no-brainer to verify.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks a lot for your example...just some further questions. 1...why can I pop exactly 37 times before my program crashes...is it just random, and that number might change after a restart? Also, How did you know that 0x00002000 was a  memory address and not just data? Also, I didn't understand what you are doing when you clean up the stack...why are you dividing to get 16 bytes?

Comment: 1) That's the garbage left by previous operations of the loading process of your application. You'll have to dig deep into the loading process of a Windows app to answer that question. Even if this number is solid on your computer, I suspect it might change on different versions of Windows. 2) I didn't. It could have been just random data. But before I posted my answer here I tried to print 0x00002000 in several different formats to see if it meant something obvious. And as it turned out, `x/1sw` showed me that it was a string.

Comment: 3) This part is Mac OS X only! Notice that I push 3 arguments to the stack before calling `write()`. Each argument takes 4 bytes on the stack, and by pushing these things to the stack I'm allocating 12 bytes for them, right? `3 args x 4 bytes = 12 bytes`. But right before calling `write()` I also do `sub esp, 4` to allocate space for another 4 bytes on the stack. By doing this, I'm allocating a total of **16 bytes** on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The private memory space allocated to your program is not guaranteed to be cleared (i.e. 0x0000). Accessing unallocated memory is generally undefined behavior, which would explain the random data you are getting.

Comment: That is certainly what's happening - those values are instructions or data from a process that has since terminated and freed up those sectors. An interesting exercise would be to try to determine what those values represented at one point.

Comment: Ahh, so nothing too interesting. Why does it crash after exactly 37 pops?